# Creating a Custom Add-in Button on MacOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a VBA script working on Windows.

On MacOS, the important content of the script is working. When I try to run the code to add a drop-down menu with buttons to run the macros, I run into:

> "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method."

This leads me to believe that MacOS doesn't support the method I'm using to add a drop-down menu with buttons.

I tried XML but ran into the same error.

I proposed alternate solutions that don't involve an add-in button in the ribbon, but the client insists that is what he wants. Really, he just wants to access the macro from any Excel workbook with the click of a button.

Dropdown menu (working Windows version): https://imgur.com/a/FbrIk92

```vb
Private Sub AddAltaMenu()
    Dim HelpMenu, Tbar, SubMenu, NewButn, NewMenuItem As Object
    Call RemoveAltaMenu
 
    Set HelpMenu = CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=30010)
    If HelpMenu Is Nothing Then
        Set Tbar = CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Temporary:=True)
    Else
        Set Tbar = CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
                                               Before:=HelpMenu.Index, Temporary:=True)
    End If
    Tbar.Caption = "&Alta"
 
    Set SubMenu = Tbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 'ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
    With SubMenu
        .Caption = "&Generate GP Reports..."
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "MenuMacros.GenerateGPWorksheets"
    End With
 
    Set SubMenu = Tbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With SubMenu
        .Caption = "Generate GP Data &Template"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "MenuMacros.GenerateImportTemplate"
    End With
 
'    Set SubMenu = Tbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
'    With SubMenu
'        .Caption = "&Uninstall..."
'        .Style = msoButtonCaption
'        .OnAction = "MenuMacros.AddinUnInstall"
'        .BeginGroup = True
'    End With
 
    Set SubMenu = Tbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With SubMenu
        .Caption = "&About..."
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "MenuMacros.AboutAltaAddIn"
        .BeginGroup = True
    End With
 
    AltaMenuDisplayed = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add your code as text (and remove the image of it) and confirm on which line the error occurs. For more advice on how to ask questions (including "DO NOT post images of code"), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).